# Dojo not loading module forced to use require

Tags: module, dojo, amd

I am loading a utility module in a few different widgets. This module just contains a bunch of DOM events like this:

```
openPointPicker: function() {
        fx.animateProperty({
          node:"point-picker",
          properties: {
            top: { end: 60, start:-500 }
          }
        }).play();
        domClass.add("point-picker", "menu-open");
      },
      closePointPicker: function() {
        fx.animateProperty({
          node:"point-picker",
          properties: {
            top: { end: -500, start:60 }
          }
        }).play();
        domClass.remove("point-picker", "menu-open");
      },
```

I use it all over the place in my app and it always loads just fine. Except in one case. I have a widget that needs to use it so I created it like this:

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dojo/text!./templates/PMS.html",
  "dojo/dom-construct",
  "app/menus", //this loads in plenty of other widgets and files, but not here
  "dojo/domReady!"
],
  function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template, domConstruct, menus) {

    return declare("PMS",[_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        widgetsInTemplate: true,
        symbol:null,
        layer:null,

        constructor: function() {
          console.log(menus); //empty object
        },
        postMixInProperties: function() {

        },
        postCreate: function() {

        },
        chooseLocation: function() {
          menus.openPointPicker();
          var handle = topic.subscribe('location-picked', function(locationInfo) {
            //stuff 
            handle.remove();
          });
        }

      }
    );
  });
```

When trying to fire the 'chooseLocation' method, it calls menus.openPointPicker(); That fails with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'openPointPicker'
```

Now, what I CAN do is specifically require "app/menus" like this:

```
chooseLocation: function() {
      require(["app/menus"], function(menus) {
        menus.openPointPicker();
        var handle = topic.subscribe('location-picked', function(locationInfo) {
          // some other stuff
          handle.remove();
        });
      });


    }
```

But why is that necessary? I don't need to do that in any of the other widgets where I use this module. I'm confused.

EDIT: The plot definitely thickens. I copied the menus.js module to menus2.js. I changed that in my list of modules to load. It now loads just fine. I obviously can't have 2 files doing the exact same thing, but it appears this isn't something I am doing wrong. Looks like some sort of bug in the Dojo AMD loader.

FINAL EDIT: Looks like I had a circular reference in my menus.js module. I had the same reference in my menus2.js test file, so I don't know why that worked. But regardless, it's been refactored.

Comment: Is the above code your exact dependency list and callback function?  It sounds like maybe there is a mismatch between the dependency list and the parameter names in the callback

Comment: Yep. I have "needs more Dojo" turned on in IntelliJ to highlight those mismatches. I counted params vs dependency imports.. but anything is possible. Where do you see it?